Как сделать запрос в базу данных чтобы по условию WHERE выводились любые значения столбцов по некоторым переменным?
Я сформировал запрос в базу данных
$dta = "SELECT * FROM shiny_name  WHERE Ширина = '".$data['Ширина']."' AND Профиль = '".$data['Профиль']."' AND Диаметр = '".$data['Диаметр']."'  AND Бренд = '".$data['Бренд']."'  AND Авто = '".$data['Авто']."' " ;

мне нужно чтобы по некоторым значениям переменных выводились любые значения. т.е. как сделать чтобы например Ширина = 'любые' а остальные переменные имели определенные значения. Можно так сделать на php ?
или сделать так чтобы некоторые переменные не участвовали в поиске хотя были в запросе.

Просто убрать выборку по ширине из запроса?)

Ну или если поле может быть NULL, то сделать ... WHERE Ширина IS NOT NULL AND ..., если ширина обязана быть задана

Да, именно убрать выборку например по ширине, но при этом чтобы в запросе участвовала именно переменная

Кто мешает написать код, который например добавляет выборку например по ширине, если например она  нужна, и не добавляет, если например не нужна?

В самом простом варианте тупо не добавлять условие, если оно не нужно. Например
$params = [];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM shiny_name WHERE 1";
if ($data['Ширина'] !== "любые")
    $sql .= " AND Ширина = ?";
    $params[] = $data['Ширина'];
}

И так далее. И потом
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);

Но в принципе можно все сделать и прямо в запросе, чтобы "по условию WHERE выводились либо любые значения, либо выполнялось условие" если переформулировать корявый заголовок вопроса.
Можно написать двойное условие, которое будет возвращать все строки, если значение равно null, или искать по нему, если не равно. Для этого значение надо передавать в запрос два раза, вида
(значение is null OR условие)

При этом запросы должны быть параметризованные, а не вот это вот всё.
Например
$name = !empty($_GET['name']) ? "%".$_GET['name']."%" : null;
$car  = !empty($_GET['car'])  ? $_GET['car'] : null;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE (? is null or name LIKE ?)
AND   (? is null or car=?)";


$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$name, $name, $car, $car]);
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // печатаем результат
}


Ладно, убедили, удалил тот вариант.

? is null это ж не сработает. name is null or name LIKE ? должно быть.

@u_mulder name is null будет искать колонки, в которых name is null. А надо чтобы все.

Ааааа, вкурил, хитро.
